# Determining induced action on cohomology.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider the map $f:S^3 \times S^3 \to S^3 \times S^3$ given by $(z_0,z_1)\mapsto (z_1, -z_0)$. Write $f$ as composition of $g \circ h $, where $h$ is $(z_0,z_1)\mapsto (z_0, -z_1)$ and $g$ is $(z_0,z_1)\mapsto (z_1, z_0)$. Then the corresponding map induced by $h$ on $3^{rd}$ cohomology group with $\Bbb Z$-coefficient is given by $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$(as the degree of the antipodal map is $(-1)^{n+1}=1$ in this case) and that of $g$ is given by $B=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$.  So the induced map by $f$ on $3^{rd}$ cohomology group is $AB$ i.e. $\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$. But this must be wrong as then the Lefschetz number $L(f)= 1+ (-1)^3 \cdot0+ (-1)^6\cdot1=2\neq 0$. But $f$ is a free action. So contradiction. Please help me to find my mistake.

I am learning Algebraic Topology by myself. Sorry, incase this a trivial question.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Of course, you mean $h\circ g$.

Comment: The trace on $H_6$ is $-1$; the map reverses orientation.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How to tell a map is orientation preserving or reversing? One way to check I know is to look at the degree of the induced map on top homology. But here how should I know it is orientation reversing assuming I don't know the degree of the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is that the degree of the map is $-1$, not $1$. If $\alpha$ is the generator of the top cohomology of the first factor and $\beta$ that of the second, then note that $\pi_1^*\alpha\cup\pi_2^*\beta = (-1)^{3\cdot 3}\pi_2^*\beta\cup\pi_1^*\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify myself. So on the $3^{rd}$ cohomology the induced action of $f$ is correct and given by the above matrix $AB=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$.  And on the $H^6$ it is $-1$. Please tell whether this is correct or not?

Comment: Yes, @mathstudent.